# shortening a switch case in PHP

Tags: php

the code works fine below on my php file. However currently i'd like to know how else could i optimize the file below.

Basically if someone could show me how to shorten the code, that would be great, a for loop here would be slightly difficult as people can select different rooms, so depending on their rooms, i'll need to insert twice.

From room 1 to 4, i'll insert 3A & 3B, for room 5 and 13, i'll insert 4A & 4B.

```
switch($fromlocation){  
                                    case 'Room 1':                                          
                if($mysqli->query($level3Asql)===TRUE){ echo 'inserted a new entry into the table Room 3A!'; } else { echo 'There is an error upon insertion in table 3A.'; }
                if($mysqli->query($level3Bsql)===TRUE){ echo 'inserted a new entry into the table Room 3B!'; } else { echo 'There is an error upon insertion in table 3B.'; }                               
                                        break;
                                    case 'Room 2':
                if($mysqli->query($level3Asql)===TRUE){ echo 'inserted a new entry into the table Room 3A!'; } else { echo 'There is an error upon insertion in table 3A.'; }
                if($mysqli->query($level3Bsql)===TRUE){ echo 'inserted a new entry into the table Room 3B!'; } else { echo 'There is an error upon insertion in table 3B.'; }                               
                                        break;
                                    case 'Room 3':
                if($mysqli->query($level3Asql)===TRUE){ echo 'inserted a new entry into the table Room 3A!'; } else { echo 'There is an error upon insertion in table 3A.'; }
                if($mysqli->query($level3Bsql)===TRUE){ echo 'inserted a new entry into the table Room 3B!'; } else { echo 'There is an error upon insertion in table 3B.'; }                               
                                        break;
                                    case 'Room 4':
                if($mysqli->query($level3Asql)===TRUE){ echo 'inserted a new entry into the table Room 3A!'; } else { echo 'There is an error upon insertion in table 3A.'; }
                if($mysqli->query($level3Bsql)===TRUE){ echo 'inserted a new entry into the table Room 3B!'; } else { echo 'There is an error upon insertion in table 3B.'; }                               
                                        break;
                                    case 'Room 5':
                if($mysqli->query($level4Asql)===TRUE){ echo 'inserted a new entry into the table Room 4A!'; } else { echo 'There is an error upon insertion in table 4A.'; }
                if($mysqli->query($level4Bsql)===TRUE){ echo 'inserted a new entry into the table Room 4B!'; } else { echo 'There is an error upon insertion in table 4B.'; }                               
                                        break;
                                    case 'Room 6':
                if($mysqli->query($level4Asql)===TRUE){ echo 'inserted a new entry into the table Room 4A!'; } else { echo 'There is an error upon insertion in table 4A.'; }
                if($mysqli->query($level4Bsql)===TRUE){ echo 'inserted a new entry into the table Room 4B!'; } else { echo 'There is an error upon insertion in table 4B.'; }                               
                                        break;  
                                    case 'Room 7':
                if($mysqli->query($level4Asql)===TRUE){ echo 'inserted a new entry into the table Room 4A!'; } else { echo 'There is an error upon insertion in table 4A.'; }
                if($mysqli->query($level4Bsql)===TRUE){ echo 'inserted a new entry into the table Room 4B!'; } else { echo 'There is an error upon insertion in table 4B.'; }                               
                                        break;
                                    case 'Room 8':
                if($mysqli->query($level4Asql)===TRUE){ echo 'inserted a new entry into the table Room 4A!'; } else { echo 'There is an error upon insertion in table 4A.'; }
                if($mysqli->query($level4Bsql)===TRUE){ echo 'inserted a new entry into the table Room 4B!'; } else { echo 'There is an error upon insertion in table 4B.'; }                               
                                        break;
                                    case 'Room 9':
                if($mysqli->query($level4Asql)===TRUE){ echo 'inserted a new entry into the table Room 4A!'; } else { echo 'There is an error upon insertion in table 4A.'; }
                if($mysqli->query($level4Bsql)===TRUE){ echo 'inserted a new entry into the table Room 4B!'; } else { echo 'There is an error upon insertion in table 4B.'; }                               
                                        break;
                                    case 'Room 10':
                if($mysqli->query($level4Asql)===TRUE){ echo 'inserted a new entry into the table Room 4A!'; } else { echo 'There is an error upon insertion in table 4A.'; }
                if($mysqli->query($level4Bsql)===TRUE){ echo 'inserted a new entry into the table Room 4B!'; } else { echo 'There is an error upon insertion in table 4B.'; }                               
                                        break;
                                    case 'Room 11':
                if($mysqli->query($level4Asql)===TRUE){ echo 'inserted a new entry into the table Room 4A!'; } else { echo 'There is an error upon insertion in table 4A.'; }
                if($mysqli->query($level4Bsql)===TRUE){ echo 'inserted a new entry into the table Room 4B!'; } else { echo 'There is an error upon insertion in table 4B.'; }                               
                                        break;
                                    case 'Room 12':
                if($mysqli->query($level4Asql)===TRUE){ echo 'inserted a new entry into the table Room 4A!'; } else { echo 'There is an error upon insertion in table 4A.'; }
                if($mysqli->query($level4Bsql)===TRUE){ echo 'inserted a new entry into the table Room 4B!'; } else { echo 'There is an error upon insertion in table 4B.'; }                               
                                        break;
                                    case 'Room 13':
                if($mysqli->query($level4Asql)===TRUE){ echo 'inserted a new entry into the table Room 4A!'; } else { echo 'There is an error upon insertion in table 4A.'; }
                if($mysqli->query($level4Bsql)===TRUE){ echo 'inserted a new entry into the table Room 4B!'; } else { echo 'There is an error upon insertion in table 4B.'; }                               
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        echo "Something went wrong :(";
                                    }
```

Comment: it should be optimized earlier, at the stage whare you are creating all these $level4Asql. there should be only one query.

Comment: I agree with @YourCommonSense completely, this looks to static.It's not how it's done.You should post your database schema might be somebody will lead you the right path :D

Comment: Hi everyone, the SQL query is actually right above this code, sorry for not posting to it earlier but i've added that in, but thank you for the comments!

Comment: So all your queries are differ by only two values. What about making these values variables and in the end you will have to run 2 queries only?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: Hi @Vogel612  thank you for the heads up, apologies for the mistake as i'm still kinda new in code review. will take a look on that. 

-Your Common Sense i have some static values on the initial query that i have though, and unfortunately as i'm still kinda new in php therefore i might not exactly know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Because your conditions are between two numbers you can shorten it down to 2 if statements.

The first step would be to retrieve the room number from the string.

```
$matches = [];
// Here we use a regex to get the room location
preg_match('/\d+/', $roomLocation, $matches);

$roomNumber = (int)$matches[0];
```

The next step would be do your conditionals.

```
if ($roomNumber >= 1 && $roomNumber <= 4) {
     // Insert into DB 
} elseif ($roomNumber >= 5 && $roomNumber <= 13) {
    // Insert into DB
}
```

An extra bonus step would be to to move your SQL queries into a method that handles the success/failure of the queries. eg.

```
private function insertIntoRoom3 () { /** Handle room 3 SQL **/}
private function insertIntoRoom4 () { /** Handle room 4 SQL **/}
```

This would mean you don't pollute your if statements with more if statements related to handling SQL. They're abstracted away into their own functions.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Hi Brok3nKeys! thanks for the answer! i'll definitely give this a try and see and update back on the status of the query. I've not thought of this before, this is definitely a great insight!